# Computing Cosine Similarity of a Matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix of size 56K X 8.5K. It is binary preference matrix.

Now I want to get the cosine similarity of each columns and some more operations as follows:

1). Before taking cosine similarity, normalize the rows of the matrix to unity (L2 norm).

2). Take cosine similarity

3). Make the diagonal elements of cosine similarity matrix to zero. Don't want similarity measure of same column with itself.

4). For each column of cosine similarity matrix if a value in that column is NOT in the top 20 values of that column then make that value to zero. Basically keeping only top 20 values of each column rest making it to zero.

To do this, Cosine similarity of the matrix would be just

```
np.dot(X.T,X)
```

where X is both row and column normalized. Row because we have to do that as per condition 1 above, and if we normalize the columns of a matrix and then take dot product of that with itself it would give cosine similarity (also called correlation).

To implement above conditions except the last , I did this:

```
#Row normalization
for x in range(b.shape[0]):
    b[x]=b[x]/(np.linalg.norm(b[x]).round(decimals=4))

# Column Normalization   
for x in range(b.shape[1]):
    b[:,x]=b[:,x]/(np.linalg.norm(b[:,x]).round(decimals=4))

M=np.dot(b.T,b)

# Fill Diagonal with zero

np.fill_diagonal(M,0)
```

Two problems:

I). I am sure this would be slow since I am iterating two times. Any faster method to normalize?

II) When I do this

```
for x in range(b.shape[0]):
        b[x]=b[x]/(np.linalg.norm(b[x]).round(decimals=4))
```

It is giving a row with zero populated. I think it might be rounding issue so even tried round function but still zero is getting populated. If i just take one row and do it, it works fine. Doing over whole matrix in a for loop is giving a matrix of zeros. Why is that?

So if someone can help in above I and II and also suggest a solution for 4 in the beginning that would be very helpful.